# 403 Forbidden when doing AJAX call to non-restful action within restful controller

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-5, cancancan

I have a `Profile` model that I am trying to update via AJAX.

This is my `routes.rb`:

```
  resources :profiles do
    member do
      patch :speed_rating
      patch :dribbling_rating
      patch :passing_rating
      patch :tackling_rating
    end
  end
```

Which generates the following routes:

```
speed_rating_profile_path   PATCH   /profiles/:id/speed_rating(.:format)    
profiles#speed_rating

dribbling_rating_profile_path   PATCH   /profiles/:id/dribbling_rating(.:format)    
profiles#dribbling_rating

passing_rating_profile_path PATCH   /profiles/:id/passing_rating(.:format)  
profiles#passing_rating

tackling_rating_profile_path    PATCH   /profiles/:id/tackling_rating(.:format) 
profiles#tackling_rating
```

This is my `ProfilesController`:

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_profile, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :invite_user, :speed_rating, :tackling_rating, :dribbling_rating, :passing_rating]
  authorize_resource except: [:dashboard]
  skip_authorization_check only: :dashboard

  def speed_rating
    binding.pry
  end

  def dribbling_rating
    binding.pry
  end

  def passing_rating
    binding.pry
  end

  def tackling_rating
    binding.pry
  end

  private
    def set_profile
      @profile = Profile.friendly.find(params[:id])
    end

    def profile_params
      params.require(:profile).permit(:id, :first_name, :last_name, :dob, :height, :weight, :bib_color, videos_attributes: [:id, :url, :video, :vimeo_url, :vimeo_embed_code, :official, :video_cache, :remove_video, :_destroy], transcripts_attributes: [:id, :url, :name, :transcript, :remove_transcript, :url_cache, :_destroy])
    end
```

In my `profile.js`, I am doing this:

```
  var url = "/profiles/" + _profile_id + "/" + _rating_type + "_rating/?" + _rating_type + "=" + button.innerText

  $.ajax({
    type: "PATCH",
    url: url,
    success: function(result){
      console.log(_profile_id + "'s " + _rating_type + " was successfully updated.");
      console.log(result);
    },
    error: function(result){
      console.log(_profile_id + "'s " + _rating_type + " was successfully updated.");
      console.log(result);
    }
  })
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
jquery.self-bd7ddd3….js?body=1:10255 PATCH http://localhost:3000/profiles/rebecca-nitzsche-st-george-s-college/dribbling_rating/?dribbling=6 403 (Forbidden)
```

**Edit 1**

I am using CanCanCan for authorization.

One thing I tried is I added those new actions to the list of exceptions for authorization, specifically like this:

```
authorize_resource except: [:dashboard, :speed_rating, :dribbling_rating, :tackling_rating, :passing_rating]
```

So far that seems to be working. However, does this make my app insecure?

How do I get this to work within the confines of my correct authorization to make sure no user can misuse these routes if they discover them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume that this line:

```
authorize_resource except: [:dashboard]
```

is doing some form of authentication or authorization, which presumably requires user details. I can't see any provision for username or password, or session cookies, in your AJAX request. You'll need to make sure you're sending the session cookie with the AJAX request so that the request can be authorized succesfully.

You may be able to do this by including an `xhrFields` object on the call to `$.ajax`:

```
$.ajax({
    'type': 'PATCH',
    'url': 'whatever',
    'xhrFields': {
        'withCredentials': true
    }
    // whatever other AJAX options you need
});
```

Comment: I like your line of thinking, but that doesn't work :(

Comment: You were right with the cause, it is just the prescription you were a bit wrong on. I updated the question with what I tried and what worked. But that feels like not the best approach, from a security perspective. How can I make sure those actions are still restricted to the authorization rules managed by CanCanCan?